# How to add an embedded image to a script?

Tags: image, email, powershell, embed

I am completely stumped. I am trying to add an embedded image to a notification email. The only scripts i can find are using .net to create a new email object.Can this only be done using .net to create an email object? Any Ideas

```
#################################################
# Configure the following variables….
# expireindays1 + 2 = At what count of days left on a password do you want a notification?
$smtpServer=”smtprelay.domain.com”
$expireindays1 = 5
#$expireindays2 = 1
$from = “Technology Helpdesk <technologyhelpdesk@domain.com>”
#################################################

#Get Users From AD who are enabled
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$users = get-aduser -filter * -Properties enabled, GivenName, passwordneverexpires, passwordexpired, emailaddress, passwordlastset |where {$_.Enabled -eq “True”} | where { $_.PasswordNeverExpires -eq $false } | where { $_.passwordexpired -eq $false }

foreach ($user in $users)
{
$Name = (Get-ADUser $user | foreach { $_.Name})
$UserID = (Get-ADUser $user -Properties *).Samaccountname
$emailaddress = $user.emailaddress
$passwordSetDate = (get-aduser $user -properties passwordlastset | foreach { $_.PasswordLastSet })
$PasswordPol = (Get-AduserResultantPasswordPolicy $user)
# Check for Fine Grained Password
if (($PasswordPol) -ne $null)
{
$maxPasswordAge = ($PasswordPol).MaxPasswordAge
}

else
{
$maxPasswordAge = (Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy).MaxPasswordAge
}

$expireson = $passwordsetdate + $maxPasswordAge
$today = (get-date)
$daystoexpire = (New-TimeSpan -Start $today -End $Expireson).Days
#$subject=


$body = @' 
#<html>  
  <body>  
    <img src="cid:image1"><br>  
  <b>$UserID : Your password will expire soon</b>
<br>
<br>
<br>
Dear $name,<br>

Your password will expire in $daystoexpire days.  Please change your password before it expires to avoid password related problems. .<br>
<br>
<br>
<b>Password complexity rules:<br> 
<br>
- Must be 7 or 8 characters long<br>
- Must contain at least 1 uppercase letter<br> 
- Must contain at least 1 lowercase letter<br>
- Must contain at least 1 number<br> 
- Must NOT contain repeating characters (e.g., aa, 11)</b><br> 
<br>
<br>
Please use the following steps to change your password:<br> 
- Press CTRL+ALT+DEL<br> 
- Click Change a password…<br> 
- Verify your User ID is correct, then type in your old and new passwords (you cannot use previously used passwords)<br> 
- After the change is complete, you will be prompted that your password has been changed<br>
- If you have a Blackberry, iPhone, or iPad, those devices will need your new password as soon as your password has been changed<br>
<br>
If you have questions, or need assistance updating your passwords, please contact the Technology Help Desk. <br>
  </body>  
#</html>  
'@  

if (($daystoexpire -eq $expireindays1))

# -or ($daystoexpire -eq $expireindays2))


{
#Send-Mailmessage -smtpServer $smtpServer -from $from -to user@domain.com -subject $subject -body $body -bodyasHTML -priority High











####################################################################################################################







$images = @{ 
    image1 = "c:\temp\action needed.png"  
}  


$params = @{ 
    InlineAttachments = $images 
    #Attachments = 'C:\temp\action needed.png'
    Body = $body 
    BodyAsHtml = $true 
    Subject = ”Your password will expire in $daystoExpire days”
    From = "Technology Helpdesk <technologyhelpdesk@domain.com>"  
    To = 'user@domain.com' 
    #Cc = 'recipient2@domain.com', 'recipient3@domain.com' 
    SmtpServer = 'smtprelay.domain.com' 

} 

Send-MailMessage @params


}

}
```

Comment: Does this help? http://winsysadm.net/send-mail-with-inline-embedded-images-with-powershell/

Comment: The phantom downvoters strike again. Don't be an anonymous downvoter, speak up so that people can improve their questions.

Comment: @Ernesto, please add as an answer rather than a comment. It is a valid answer but the details should be listed here for future reference.

Comment: Ernesto, I already tried adding the .net code in that link in place of send-mailmessage but it did not work.

Comment: I did not add as an answer becuase I did not know if it would help you. I don't know why someone downvoted this without explaining. 
Maybe you need something configured to access .net framework classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This code](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Send-MailMessage-3a920a6d) does not use the dot net classes. I hope it helps.

```
$images = @{ 
    image1 = 'c:\temp\test.jpg' 
    image2 = 'C:\temp\test2.png' 
}  

$body = @' 
<html>  
  <body>  
    <img src="cid:image1"><br> 
    <img src="cid:image2"> 
  </body>  
</html>  
'@  

$params = @{ 
    InlineAttachments = $images 
    Attachments = 'C:\temp\attachment1.txt', 'C:\temp\attachment2.txt' 
    Body = $body 
    BodyAsHtml = $true 
    Subject = 'Test email' 
    From = 'username@gmail.com' 
    To = 'recipient@domain.com' 
    Cc = 'recipient2@domain.com', 'recipient3@domain.com' 
    SmtpServer = 'smtp.gmail.com' 
    Port = 587 
    Credential = (Get-Credential) 
    UseSsl = $true 
} 

Send-MailMessage @params
```

BTW all credit to [David Wyatt](http://davewyatt.wordpress.com/) who created the code. He seems to be a good resource on powershell script.

Comment: It fights me every step of the way. Its a lot closer accept when i modify the $Body parameters and add variables, the variables do not work. Is it because the $Body parameter is encapsulated?

Comment: Maybe it's a syntax problem when you try to add the variables. How are you adding them?

Comment: I added them in the beginning of the script. It works with the normal send-mailmessage but not with the paramaters in the script you posted above.